# Ideal operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Can someone please explain the below to me? I assume there are standard operations for each of the lines but I'm not quite sure. $P_1$ is an ideal.

$
\begin{align*}
P_1 &= \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5} \rangle\\
&=\langle2, 1+\sqrt{-5}, 2-(1+\sqrt{-5})\rangle\\
&=\langle2, 1+\sqrt{-5}, 1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle\\
&=\langle2, 2-(1-\sqrt{-5}), 1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle\\
&=\langle2, 1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle
\end{align*}
$

And

$
\begin{align*}
P_1^2 &= \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5}\rangle^2\\
&=\langle 2+\sqrt{-5} \rangle \langle 2, 1-\sqrt{-5}\rangle\\
&=\langle 4, 2(1+\sqrt{-5}), 2(1-\sqrt{-5}),6\rangle\\
&=\langle2\rangle \langle 2, 1+\sqrt{-5}, 1-\sqrt{-5}, 3 \rangle\\
&=\langle 2\rangle \langle 1\rangle\\
&=\langle 2\rangle
\end{align*}
$

Thanks!

Edit:

Sorry, the ring is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.
What I don't understand is how do you go from one line to the other. For instance, where did the 6 come from in line 3 of $P^2_1$? how $\langle 2 \rangle$ got separated in line 4? I'm sorry... I guess these are really basic questions.

Comment: Where exactly are not "quite sure"?

Comment: You need to tell us what ring you are considering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning $P_1$. All that is happening line by line is using the fact, that the ideal does not change when you add an element of the ideal to the generators. More precisely.

Let: $\mathfrak{a}:=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be an ideal generated by $n$ elements. Now let $s\in\mathfrak{a}$. Then $\mathfrak{a}=(s,a_1,\ldots, a_n)$. Since $s$ an element of the ideal, it is a linear combination of the generators.

In $P_1$ you have an ideal being generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt{-5}$. Since $1-\sqrt{-5}=2+ (-1)\cdot (1+\sqrt{-5})$ is a linear combination of the generators, you can add it the list of generators without changing the ideal.

Then you note that $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is a linear combination of $2$ and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ and so that the ideal can also be generated by $2$ and $1-\sqrt{-5}$.

For $P_1^2$ what is happening is, that you note that the square of an ideal is generated by $a_ia_j$ for all combinations of indices $i$ and $j$. Then you do the same as in the first case. In the end you note that $(1)$ is the ring $R$ and since $\mathfrak{a}R=\mathfrak{a}$ you are done.

Comment: Many thanks!
And in $P_1^2$ line 4, how did it go from $\langle 3, 1+\sqrt{-5}, 1-\sqrt{-5}, 2\rangle$? I mean if these four elements had coefficients $0,1,0,0$ (for a linear combination) we'd get $1+\sqrt{-5}$ which can't be generated by $\langle 1 \rangle$ (I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here, but not sure what)

Comment: you have $3$ and $2$ in the generator. So that ideal also contains $1=3-2$. Thus any other value is irrelevant, because as soon as an ideal contains $1$ it is equal to $R$. $1+\sqrt{-5}$ can of course be generated by $1$. Your ring could be somthing like $R=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$. For an ideal the relation holds that if $a\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $r\in R$, then $ra\in\mathfrak{a}$. Since $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is in $R$ it is in $(1)$.